# how to build private network for real use cases like enterprise ? is it possible to use HTTPS ?

Tags: private-blockchain, private, iot

hi dear reader thank you first for reading my post appreciated  , i hope if you could help with this question mainly by providing the common ground and links to read more i only have 3 question

1- how to build a private blockchain network for enterprise like a Professional ( do i have to buy some software , any possible good open source project or any tips )

2- is it possible to assure confidentiality between node while communicating like using some sort of SSL or TLS to encrypt the communication

3- lets say that you explain 1 for me ( thanks again for your time ) , is it possible to use like a centralized authority that check who has permission to write or read the blockchain ( lets say like IoT device we need to give him some sort of key to be able to interact with the private blockchain , and where do we store those key for the IoT device )

Answer (score 0):

1 - Yes, you can install a eth-client such as https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started to create a private blockchain.

2 - Yes, you wouldn't need to manually do it, just set the flags on the geth client when you run it

3 - A permissioned blockchain is possible, in this case you would have a allow list of geth clients

Comment: thank you so much mate , do i find everything on the link ?

Comment: yeah the link should have about everything that you need